# Remove a folder from url when folder still exists with .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, path, directory

I'm starting over a website. I want all my php files to be in a folder called `files` so none of these will be in the root.

I would like to not see the folder `files` on the url so when I access one of those files it should show `www.mywebsite.com/thefile.php` instead of `www.mywebsite.com/files/thefile.php`.

This is what I have in my .htaccess (only the index file changed).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    DirectoryIndex files/home.php
</IfModule>
```

Some extra maybe important information. This is a testing website and I've put this in a specific folder from another working website which I have made with Magento.

Comment: Why not set your `DocumentRoot` to `files/` directory?

Comment: Would other folders I have in my actual root still count? I mean, I have some other folders like imgs, css and js for these kind of files.

Comment: So you only want `.php` files in `/files/`?

Comment: If it is possible, yes. If not, putting the rest of folders inside of /files/ is also an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `testing/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testing/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /files/([^?]+?\.php)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+\.php)$ files/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: This is not working. I have this website into another folder like: `www.mywebsite.com/testing` where I have my `.htaccess` and then the folder `files`.

Comment: There are 2 document roots. One for the working website (inside `www`) and the other on `www/testing/` where there is the folder files (`www/testing/files/`)

Comment: When I try to access to any of my files it gives me error: Internal Server Error

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your time and patience :)